# Sistemas operativos: ¿Cuáles son las ventajas de utilizar un bootloader? ¿Por qué es mejor no colocar el SO directamente en esa dirección?

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel, ingenieria-del-software

Se entiende que el bootloader es un mini SO (sistema operativo) que carga al SO pleno; y que si se tienen varios SOs un bootloader podría preguntarnos cuál cargar.

Pero más allá de eso, si solo se utiliza un solo SO ¿Hay desventajas al colocar el SO pleno en la dirección del bootloader?

Gracias anteladas

Comment: ¿ Aparte de que no cabe ?

Comment: ¿Es sarcasmo?
De hecho el SO pleno y el bootloader van juntos en la RAM, y si evitamos el bootloader ahorramos el espacio (aunque mínimo) que ocuparía.
Si te refieres a otra cosa, esperamos tu aporte como respuesta.

Comment: En realidad un bootloader no carga ningun SO a pleno de nada. Se usa en la posicion 0 como un proxy para decirle de donde cargar un SO completo real.

Comment: El bootloader es un código que se carga en RAM para que precisamente cargue (load) el SO, por eso se llama bootloader.

Comment: Las etiquetas están fuera de contexto

Comment: No, no es sarcasmo: mi Linux-4.15, solo el núcleo (sin módulos) ocupa mas de 8Mb. La última vez que miré, los sectores físicos del disco tenían 512bytes ( y antes de UEFI, había que descontar el tamaño de la tabla de particiones). Así que son razones puramente prácticas.

Comment: Esta pregunta no trata sobre programación dentro del ámbito definido en el Centro de ayuda. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Primero más que por ventajas, fue una necesidad debido a la limitación de los BIOS, pues no podía direccionar el disco duro. Además de tampoco tener la capacidad de usar el sistema de archivos con el cual se localiza el kernel.
- Da la posibilidad de darnos a elegir entre más de un SO a iniciar.
- Permite un desarrollo independiente entre el HW y sus versiones de BIOS y los OS, incluso permitir que los UEFI sustituyan al BIOS.
- Permite un desarrollo independiente entre el HW y los formatos de sistemas de archivos.

Su ventaja general es que permite flexibilidad. Pregunta similar: 
[Why do we need a boot loader?](https://superuser.com/questions/429473/why-do-we-need-a-boot-loader)